# c# - bytes taken by long.ToString() bigger than same number as string

Tags: c#

In my application (.Net 4.6 x86) I have a class that stores an Id from different sources, which could be either a long or a string depending on the source. So internally it's saved as the string:

```
public class GenericId
{
    string _internalId;

    public GenericId(long id)
    {
        _internalId = id.ToString();
    }

    public GenericId(string id)
    {
        _internalId = id;
    }
}
```

I would have expected that the memory is taken by this instance:

```
new GenericId("0")
```

is the same as this:

```
new GenericId(0);
```

but the former one takes 12 bytes while the later takes 28 bytes.

Since I have a large number of them in memory the memory changes drastically whether it comes from one source or another.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `long.ToString()`, you are allocating a new `string` each time.

String literals in C# are created once at assembly load and then re-used: `"foo"` in one place will reference the same instance of `"foo"` in another place. No memory allocation will occur in the place you actually use the literal.

Comment: So, `_internalId = id.ToString()` creates one or two instances?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed according to the answer, it is creating a new instance of the string with each new `GenericId()` that uses a long because it isn't a string literal.

Comment: Every call to `GenericId(long)` allocates a new string. `GenericId(string)` never allocates a new string, and your use of it (passing a literal) ensures the caller isn't allocating a new string either.

Comment: @Soviut, I do understand that, but according to the OP, the size in memory is different when comparing **one instance**  of `GenericId` initialized with a `long` argument to another instance initialized with a `string` argument. So, I was curious if it has something to do with calling `ToString()` **and** assigning it to a variable.

Comment: It could be that the long value is not initially collected so the long and the string are both taking up memory.

Comment: @CoryNelson that seems the more plausible explanation. Making a test with a list of GenericId(string) effectively one instance takes 28 bytes while the rest takes 12 bytes. Thanks for the help.